# Filling A ScrollView with many items takes TOO long

Tags: android, xamarin.android, scrollview

I am currently working on a simple mp3 player as an app on my android phone. I am going through all the files on my sd card and my internal storage to find everything with the extension: ".mp3".

Simple and works fine.

I then fill out a list with all the resulting song names and when clicked, they start playing. Working fine as well BUT

I now tried this on my personal phone with 700+ songs on it and the lists are done in less than a second but now the lists are to populate a ScrollView in a foreach loop with the results. And this takes for ever:

```
 private void PopulateScrollView(List<string> content)
        {
            LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.scrollview);
            mp3 = new List<MP3object>();

            foreach (string obj in content)
            {
                WriteMetaDataToFileList(obj);

                TextView txt = new TextView(this);
                reader.SetDataSource(obj);
                txt.Text = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyTitle);
                txt.TextSize = 20;
                txt.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.Center;

                root.AddView(txt);

                txt.Click += delegate
                {
                    PlayMusic(Android.Net.Uri.Parse(obj));
                    firstStart = false;
                    txt_CurrentSong.Text = CurrentActiveSongUri.ToString();
                    btn_StartOrPause.Text = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.Pause);
                };
            }
        }
```

So, I am wonderin. What am I doing differently then my "normal" music player on my phone? I open it, and all the songs are already filled inside a ScrollView, almost NO waiting time. Appearently, going through the loop 700+ times to fill it up with the songs is way too much work, but it has to be done, right? Or am I seeing something wrong here? Some help would be AWESOME! :)

Thank you.

*** EDIT:

Also, I noted that every app that lists my files on my phone is quick as hell listing even 1000+ files in a scrollview. Clearly, my way is the incorrect way to fill a scrollview with static items from my phone. Any other ways of doing this? thank you :)

Comment: You need [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Comment: please no. god no. pleaaaaase no. no.

Comment: Creating 700 TextView controls (and scrolling through them) is what is killing your app. The whole purpose of RecyclerView (existence) is to solve those kind of problems.

Comment: Oh man!, you add the views directly to the Scrollview that its a bad practice. works if you have some views but not many. Please use a recyclerview is the best way, dont taking much time to build and its cool for performance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're hitting is that ScrollView is not made to be used with long lists of data. You're forcing Android to generate, lay out, and maintain a *huge* number of views. Instead you should look into the [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview).

RecyclerView is made to handle long lists of data elements, like your use-case of mp3 files. It handles the large amount of data by only creating the elements needed to display items that are currently on the screen (plus a couple additional items to help with smooth scrolling). This greatly reduces the memory and cpu pressure on the system and allows for the responsiveness you see in other apps. Those other apps are most likely using RecyclerView or a similar pattern.

I recommend reading through Google's guide on the RecyclerView (linked above, but also [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) for convenience) to learn how to use it. I'd also recommend using RecyclerView's built-in list-item selection functionality to handle user taps instead of your TextView.click event. Both can work, but the selection functionality will likely be more convenient as RecyclerView handles the hard parts for you.